# Compile time Error in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, cygwin

I am tring to compile an C code (**davinci_spi.c**). the corresponding header file is as follow:

```
davinci_spi.h:

    #ifndef _DAVINCI_SPI_H_
    #define _DAVINCI_SPI_H_

    struct davinci_spi_regs {
    dv_reg  gcr0;       /* 0x00 */
    dv_reg  gcr1;       /* 0x04 */
    dv_reg  int0;       /* 0x08 */
    dv_reg  lvl;        /* 0x0c */
    dv_reg  flg;        /* 0x10 */
    dv_reg  pc0;        /* 0x14 */
    dv_reg  pc1;        /* 0x18 */
    dv_reg  pc2;        /* 0x1c */
    dv_reg  pc3;        /* 0x20 */
    dv_reg  pc4;        /* 0x24 */
    dv_reg  pc5;        /* 0x28 */
    dv_reg  rsvd[3];
    dv_reg  dat0;       /* 0x38 */
    dv_reg  dat1;       /* 0x3c */
    dv_reg  buf;        /* 0x40 */
    dv_reg  emu;        /* 0x44 */
    dv_reg  delay;      /* 0x48 */
    dv_reg  def;        /* 0x4c */
    dv_reg  fmt0;       /* 0x50 */
    dv_reg  fmt1;       /* 0x54 */
    dv_reg  fmt2;       /* 0x58 */
    dv_reg  fmt3;       /* 0x5c */
    dv_reg  intvec0;    /* 0x60 */
    dv_reg  intvec1;    /* 0x64 */
    };
```

`
(I think remaining of file code is not important so not including them)

and when I am trying to compile **davinci_spi.c** I  get this error:

---

```
In file included from D:/android/android/myprojects/test1/jni/davinci_spi.c:32:
D:/android/android/myprojects/test1/jni/davinci_spi.h:6: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'dv_reg'
```

---

**Note:** I am using cygwin(with a C/C++ compiler added) and davinci_spi.c is a simple linux driver

Comment: What do you know about the C or the C++ languages (these are different languages)?

Comment: Identifiers that begin with two underscores or an underscore followed by a capital letter (like your `_DAVINCI_SPI_H_`) are reserved for use by the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet that dv_reg is not being defined.  Be sure to include the header file that defines the type dv_reg.

Comment: i think this is true answer but the header file is complete (that is a texas instrument co. suggestion). i guess we are using a wrong compiler context: bec its a davinci board driver that i used it on arm board. therefore i used "armeabi" during compile. so compiler can not recognize dv_reg type. now i want to test with arm version and after test i will derivate. thanks a lot

Comment: yes this driver can not be compile without a whole kernel compile

Answer (score 1):

Where is dv_reg declared? I can't spot neither a definition of this type nor an include of a .h-file declaring it. I'd recommend to track down where this data type is defined and include this header file into your driver file.